# How to enable HTTPS on Python 2.7 web.py?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7.5 with web.py (v0.38) installed on a Linux machine. Below is my code in the most basic form (**webhooks.py**)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import web

urls = ('/.*','WebHooks')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class WebHooks:
    def POST(self):
        raw_payload = web.data()
        json_encode = json.loads(raw_payload)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

1. I execute `python webhooks.py 9999`
2. It opens up a local port `http://0.0.0.0:9999/`

**My issue**: I have read the documentation located [here](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api) and I am stumped. Would somebody be able to help me open an HTTPS URL? `https://0.0.0.0:9999/`

**What I have tried**

Add the following into my code for testing:

```
response = app.request("/.*", https=True)
```

I would get an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'`

I solved that issue with `pip install urllib.py` and then adding `import urllib` to the top of my code but I ended up with a bunch of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 461, in _delegate
    cls = fvars[f]
KeyError: u'WebHooks'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 229, in handle
    fn, args = self._match(self.mapping, web.ctx.path)
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're headed down the wrong path, but not to worry. The `response = app.request("/.*", https=True)` bit you're trying has to do with your application *making* an https request, rather then *handling* an https request.

See http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl

Internally, web.py uses a CherryPyWSGIServer. To handle https, you need to provide the server with an ssl_certificate and ssl_key. Very simply, add a few lines before you invoke `app.run()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
    ssl_cert = '/path-to-cert.crt'
    ssl_key = '/path-to-cert.key'
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = ssl_cert
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = ssl_key
    app.run()
```

Of course, in a full solution, you'll probably want apache or nginx to handle the https portion, but the above is perfect for small applications and testing.

Comment: Thank you! I will try first thing tomorrow morning and update the status on this.

Comment: Update: Your solution worked! For other readers who are also trying this, I had to make sure I had two things prior to it working. First is, you need to install openssl-devel on your system, and the second is use pip to install pyOpenSSL.

Comment: Update: from 2019 instead of `from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer`  import 
`from cheroot.wsgi import Server as CherryPyWSGIServer`